# How do I assign a number to a letter in Java

Tags: java

I am working on a rather unique coding situation in Java. The purpose of the program I am trying to write is to take an Amateur Radio call sign, convert the letters in the call sign into numbers as defined by a list or other structure, treat the number as its face integer value, and run these numbers through several mathematical operations to output a unique "User Code" at the end. The length of characters, as well as the number itself, will vary from user to user based on their call sign, which is fine. The biggest obstacle I have encountered is that I do not want the letters to be assigned values in a 1-26 or 0-25 type pattern. I will post my code in a moment to show you. For the moment, the end use of this User Code is unimportant to this example, but suffice it to say that since I will be the only one using this particular code example I am not very concerned with doing validity checks or the like as I will ensure the integrity of the input data manually. With this being said, I do have a working solution which I will post here, but my question is not "it doesn't work" because it does work, my problem is that it is, in my opinion, bloated, and something tells me it could be cut down considerably. Here is the code, and following are some alternatives I considered but rejected:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class UserCode
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int baseNumber = 0;
        int finalNumber;
        String callSign;
        System.out.println("Enter CallSign for Code Generation: ");
        callSign = in.nextLine();
        String s = callSign.toUpperCase();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
        {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isDigit(c))
            {
                int l = Character.getNumericValue(c);
                baseNumber = baseNumber + l;
            }
            else if (Character.isLetter(c))
            {
                int letNum = 0;
                switch (c)
                {
                    case 'A':
                        letNum = 23;
                        break;
                    case 'B':
                        letNum = 17;
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        letNum = 5;
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        letNum = 11;
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                        letNum = 34;
                        break;
                    case 'F':
                        letNum = 18;
                        break;
                    case 'G':
                        letNum = 13;
                        break;
                    case 'H':
                        letNum = 31;
                        break;
                    case 'I':
                        letNum = 27;
                        break;
                    case 'J':
                        letNum = 25;
                        break;
                    case 'K':
                        letNum = 7;
                        break;
                    case 'L':
                        letNum = 25;
                        break;
                    case 'M':
                        letNum = 33;
                        break;
                    case 'N':
                        letNum = 26;
                        break;
                    case 'O':
                        letNum = 28;
                        break;
                    case 'P':
                        letNum = 16;
                        break;
                    case 'Q':
                        letNum = 14;
                        break;
                    case 'R':
                        letNum = 2;
                        break;
                    case 'S':
                        letNum = 4;
                        break;
                    case 'T':
                        letNum = 6;
                        break;
                    case 'U':
                        letNum = 8;
                        break;
                    case 'V':
                        letNum = 10;
                        break;
                    case 'W':
                        letNum = 37;
                        break;
                    case 'X':
                        letNum = 12;
                        break;
                    case 'Y':
                        letNum = 3;
                        break;
                    case 'Z':
                        letNum = 1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Call Contains a bad character. Try again. \n");
                }
            baseNumber = baseNumber + letNum;   
            }
        }
    System.out.println("\n");
    String baseStr = Integer.toString(baseNumber);
    System.out.println("The Base number is:  " + baseStr + "\n");
    int sMod = baseNumber%7;
    String sModStr = Integer.toString(sMod);
    System.out.println("The Check Digit is:  " + sModStr + "\n");
    String combine = baseStr + sModStr;
    int nextOp = Integer.parseInt(combine);
    finalNumber = nextOp * nextOp;
    String finalStr = Integer.toString(finalNumber);
    System.out.println("The User Code is:  " + finalStr + "\n");
    }
}
```

Okay, as I said this code works, but it is long. I had considered a few alternatives, none of which will really work. The first was Enum, but that obviously is outside my parameters as it produces a 1-26 incremented pattern. There are several variations of this using various for{} loops but the result there is the same. I even considered a new HashMap and map.put statements, but that's only marginally shorter and it would seem to me that creating a hashmap would, in the end, actually use more memory than my current solution. As you can see, I did not .split or use .toCharArray() since these created separate entities in memory that I did not need. All the information I needed was already contained in the string itself, except for my chosen numerical values. Finally, I could have created another class file with this assignment code, but the result is the same: the length itself hasn't been changed it's been spread over two files (and actually increased in calling the method).

Having put this out here, can anyone see any way I can shorten this code, particularly in the area of the switch{} block and still retain the same result with the same numerical values? I would be highly interested in any suggestions that can be made in this regard. BTW I didn't mention this but this is not a school assignment, this is a personal project, though my level of Java knowledge is about at that of a beginner taking my first Java class LOL. Thanks

Comment: is there a logic behind the character/number relationship or is it random?

Comment: Assuming you're really asking about the `switch`, I'd just use an array: `int[] letNums = {23, 17, 5, ...}`, then `letNum = (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') ? letNums[c - 'A'] : 0;`.

Comment: Is it intentional that `J` and `L` map to the same number? If the numbers are unique and ascending you could build a constant String `"ZRYSC..."` and use indexOf lookup to generate your number from it (and show an error if the value is `-1`)

Comment: A couple of responses: Nope it was not intentional that J and L map to the same, I've made that correction (thank you for catching that one) and one that I see here and below are the use of an array, which I like that. It's neat, clean, and just like the HashMap can be defined once and used multiple times if needed. While both answers do work and each one has a particular instance in which it would be best suited, I think in this instance I will try the array first. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of corresponding integers:

```
int[] letnums = {23, 17, 5, ... };

char c = s.charAt(i);
if (Character.isLetter(c)) {
  int letnum = letnums(c);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Well, about 2 minutes after according to my timestamps. But your answer is syntactically and logically incorrect :/

Comment: You actually need to check that `c` is in the right range for this approach. There are lots of codepoints which are "letters", but not in the range `A-Z` (`a` springs to mind).

Comment: This is the one I am going to experiment with first, though I may have to do a resource comparison between this and a few other methods. HashMap and even the Switch in its own method are both workable, it'll be interesting to see which one is the most resource-intensive. With this one I'll have to experiment with ways to map a letter to an incremental index in the array (could use a two-dimensional array or Enumerate, I'll have to play with this and see which gives me a cleaner solution). Thanks though, I'll make this code edit :)

Comment: To keep the input relevant to this and within the A-Z range the first thing I do is String s = callSign.toUpperCase(); which converts all the letter characters to upper case. This way there are only two instances (given the input is correct) which are a letter (which is now Upper) and a number (which the if{} block catches) so yep that was a concern: I didn't want to have to do a case a: case A: fallthrough catch...

Comment: Andy, can you show me where my solution is failing in syntax and logic? Again, while it's bulky, it does produce valid output with valid input, I have compiled and tested already. Or were you talking about the presented solution in this example?

Comment: @Andy Turner - Yes, you are right; the argument to letnums should be `c-x` where x is the character corresponding to the first item in the letnums array, and checked for range (as your first comment showed). At least it's not as bad as in C or C++ where there is no guarantee that the letters are contiguous

Comment: Just for kicks I have written and compiled all these solutions under different class names just to have a record for myself of different ways to do this. As far as the length of the code, I like the array, though I did use a two dimension array  `String[][] lna = {{"A","B",...}{"23","17","5"...}}` , cast (c) to String str, then tested if (str.equals(lna[0][x]) in an iterating for loop. If it matches, it pulls the value at [1][x] and parses it to Integer, then break; from the loop and continue on. It works well, and looks neat!

Comment: I also used the HashMap, although I had to play with defining the map. Took me a few times and the compiler yelling at me occasionally, but finally got HashMap<Character, Integer> lm = new HashMap<Character, Integer>(); to compile nicely and works. And you're right, it's very lean and absolutely zero lag so it works perfectly as well. I will add some sanity checks and validity checks and some error handlers, but as I said right now I am the only one using this code so I can self-validate the input and correct for it if necessary... Once again thanks a million, works like a charm both ways!

Answer (score 3):

if you want to stick with this logic then use a `HashMap<Character, Integer>` and setup only once the values like: `map.put('Z', 1);` and so on, then u don't need the switch. You can get the values by using: `map.get('Z');` which will return every time 1

it is easy to implement and easy to change the code if needed

Comment: I'm gonna check this because it does indeed work this way, and if I were going to need to reference the letter number relationship multiple times in the program this would work nicely because of the reason you mentioned is that the HashMap only needs to be defined once. I am going to have to try this one and run a debugger that will let me monitor resources so I can see how resource-intensive a HashMap is versus an array; that makes for an interesting question. Nonetheless a valid answer, so if I could upvote it I would I haven't been using stackoverflow long enough to be able to yet...

Comment: @mich HashMap is very lean on resources and lightning fast. IMHO this is the best approach, and unlike the array-based approach (that you have currently accepted), won't throw an exception if you try to encode a character other than a letter.

Comment: I have several Java editors and IDE's on here, two of which have the ability to monitor resources while the program runs (I believe it's the NetBeans, though IntelliJ may also do this). I think what I will do is copy the code and create a different class name (and file name) and test both methods. As for the exception, that's a good point, and I really should have this in a try...catch...finally anyhow to catch exceptions (I likely will especially if there's ever a reason to give this code to anyone else) but since I am currently the only one using it I bypassed that step to test the logic.

Comment: I do have a question on this logic before I proceed with coding this for testing: what difference, in resources or implementation, would there be between using HashMap or HashTable? I know that the table is synchronized whereas the map is not, but what exactly does that mean, both on the system level (and resources) and on the user interaction level? Also, since I do not intend for this table (or map either way) to ever change, should I make it final to protect it against changes?

Comment: @michael use a HashMap. Hashtable is used internally by HashMap, but it's not a class you should be dealing with directly. The Map interface is what you want. Also, "performance" and "resources" are the last things you should be thinking about. HashMap operations are fast: about 400 nanoseconds for a `put()` (a one-time cost for you) and about 100 nanoseconds for a `get()`. The memory footprint for 26 entries is virtually zero compared the the JVM itself. Just use HashMap and move on.